# What i wrong with my html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

from the code below, I get the following error:

/home/ubuntu/workspace/portfolio/app/views/projects/_project_form.html.erb:36: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

because it is a syntax error, I am guessing I wont need to provide other details but if you guys need me to post more feel free to ask.

```
    <%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= "#{pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this project from being saved:" %>
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li>
            <%= msg %>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :client %>
      <p>
        <%= @project.client.name %>
      </p>
      <%= f.hidden_field:note_id, value: @project.client.id  %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :project_description %>
    <%= f.text_area :project_description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :project_timescale %>
    <%= f.text_field :project_timescale %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the form:--

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= "#{pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error")} prohibited this project from being saved:" %>
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :note_id, value: @project.client.id  %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :client %>
      <p>
        <%= @project.client.name %>
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :project_description %>
    <%= f.text_area :project_description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :project_timescale %>
    <%= f.text_field :project_timescale %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error is coming due to extra `<% end %>` below the `hidden field`